# Setting up leaflet map in R using if/else if/else filtering

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny, leaflet-r, mapview

I'm trying to put together a map for work. Right now, the script looks as such [(The shape file data can be downloaded here)](https://github.com/gooponyagrinch/blob):

```
library(tigris)
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

nv <- st_read('./testdata.shp') %>% mutate(super_region = case_when(region %in% c('1','2') ~ 'A', !region %in% c('1','2') ~ 'B')) %>% mutate(turf = as.character(turf)) %>% select(super_region,region,turf,areas,sales) %>% st_sf()

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(8,
           width = 10, offset = 1,
           tags$h3("Select Area"),
           panel(
             selectizeGroupUI(
               id = "filters",
               params = list(
                 SR = list(inputId = "super_region", title = "Super Region:"),
                 Reg = list(inputId = "region", title = "Region:"),
                 Turf = list(inputId = "turf", title = "Turf"),
                 Areas = list(inputId = "areas", title = "Areas:")
               ))
           ),
           leafletOutput("test")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  res_mod <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "filters",
    data = nv,
    vars = c('super_region', 'region', 'turf', 'areas')
  )


map_data <- reactive({

if(is.null(input$super_region) & is.null(input$region) & is.null(input$turf) & is.null(input$areas)) {

  md <- res_mod() %>% st_sf() %>% st_buffer(0) %>% group_by(super_region) %>% summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry))

}


else if(!is.null(input$super_region)) {

    md <- res_mod() %>% filter(super_region %in% input$super_region) %>% st_sf() %>% st_buffer(0) %>% group_by(region) %>% summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry))

}

else if(!is.null(input$region)) {

    md <- res_mod() %>% filter(region %in% input$region) %>% st_sf() %>% st_buffer(0) %>% group_by(turf) %>% summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry))

}

  else if(!is.null(input$turf)) {

    md <- res_mod() %>% filter(turf %in% input$turf) %>% st_sf() %>% st_buffer(0) %>% group_by(areas) %>% summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry))

  }  

else {

  md <- res_mod() %>% filter(areas %in% input$areas) %>% st_sf() %>% st_buffer(0) %>% group_by(areas) %>% summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry))

}

})

output$test <- renderLeaflet({

  res <- map_data()

  mapview(res)@map

})

}  

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

While I thought I had set it up correctly, it is not working as intended, and it appears my issue is with the combination `if`, `else if` and `else` statements I put together, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is what I would expect it to look like:

**When the map first loads and no filters are selected:**

[image: When the map first loads and no filters are selected]

**When only super_region is selected. In this example, I used super_region B**

[image]

**When region is then selected (super_region can be blank or have a value). In this example, I used region 3:**

[image]

**When turf is then selected (super_region, and region can be blank or have a value, it doesn't matter). In this example, I used turf 3A:

[image]

**And finally, when areas is selected (super_region, region, and turf can be blank or have a value, it doesn't matter. In this example, I used areas 1167 is selected:

[image]

Does this make sense? So basically, the default setup is showing just the super_regions. Then for each ensuing level, it groups by the one below it.